# How to handle Unicode Character in REST Api built using Spring and JAX-RS...?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, unicode

My API is developed using JAX-RS and Spring framework.
I am calling another API which returns a string containing special character like copyright symbol, dollar sign, euro symbol.
I am assigning the same value to one field in API and sending that response. When i test my API in SOAP-UI or PostMan tool 'm not getting special character instead it is printing some garbage character.

I tried Apache's,

```
StingEscapeUtils.unEscapeJava(String str);
```

But it's not working for me, Please suggest me some solution for this.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to call the API?  What character encoding are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This to me seems like you need to define as part of your heading the encoding type of your response. For example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This lets the receiving end know that this is a text/html document which has utf-8 encoded characters.

For more information please refer to the following link

http://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

OR

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

OR

// HttpUriRequest request
request.addHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);